# Django 1.7.2 POST without using FormView

Tags: django, post, http-status-code-405

Fellows, I am now implementing simple app using Django 1.7.2
I am looking for handling post method without using FormView.

I tried to search every page in Websites, but I could not solve this problem

Every time I tried to solve it, I got 405 Error(Method not Allowed)

This is code from gist I pasted it.
URL : https://gist.github.com/BOBTommy/aeb96a6e9413fddc85a2

If you can't access it, please tell me that. I will paste this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url patterns are messed up, and your form redirects to the `LoginView`, not your `LoginProcessView`. This will fix it:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
    url(r'^login_process/$', LoginProcessView.as_view(), name="login_process"),
)
```

login.html (Remove slash before `login_process`, add one after. Or better yet, use the `url` template tag).

```
...
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="login_process/" method="POST">
...
```

Comment: yeah, that's the convention.

Comment: I fixed this problem using method decorator in CBV, and thank you for your answer.